# Calculate Tax Based on Shipping Method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I charge different tax rates based on the shipping method a customer selects at checkout in Woocommerce? My store has one shipping option that lets international customers avoid the 7% VAT charged here in Thailand.

Here's how to disable taxes when Local Pickup is selected as the shipping option according to Woocommerce documentation:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_apply_base_tax_for_local_pickup', '__return_false' );
```

But how do I disable taxes on a custom shipping option?

I've started to work out a solution, but I could use some help with line 2. i.e. How to get the current shipping method?

```
function remove_tax_for_fob( $cart ) {
    $ok_remove = get_shipping_method( 'FOB' );
    if ($ok_remove){ 
        $cart->remove_taxes();
}
return $cart;
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'remove_tax_for_fob' );
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/shipping-method-api/) states that in the `calculate_shipping` method of your custom shipping option you can set `'taxes' => false` . So before you set the rate check if the client is international, and then add the tax as required.

Comment: @AnandShah It was my understanding that setting 'taxes' => 'false' here just excludes taxes from the shipping cost calculation, not that it excludes taxes from the order amount.  Am I mistaken? That would be great if so!

Comment: You are right, sorry I misunderstood the requirement. So whether to charge tax or not on the entire order is dependent on the shipping method the customer chooses?

Comment: `WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt = true` if the custom shipping option is selected will set the tax to 0

Comment: Correct, customers who choose a certain shipping method (FOB) are tax exempt. Can you tell me where `WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt = true` needs to go to make that happen? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I also came across this method `$cart->remove_taxes();` that looks promising.

Comment: Yes, when I went through the code of Cart class, I did find that method too but couldn't get it work. If you manage to get it working, please share your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91188/discussion-between-j8d-and-anand-shah).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. Thanks for your help, Anand Shah!

```
/* Remove tax from cart for FOB orders */
function remove_tax_for_fob( $cart ) {
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 
    if($chosen_shipping =='FOB') {
        $cart->remove_taxes();
    }
    return $cart;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'remove_tax_for_fob' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, will need a bit of polishing though

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit','custom_review_order_before_submit');

function custom_review_order_before_submit() {

    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 

    if( "FOB" == $chosen_shipping ) {

        WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt = true;

    } else {

        WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt = false;

    }    

}
```